# GeoPandas plot shapefile by ignoring some administrative areas

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, geopandas

Shapefile Data: The entire world (**with 5 administrative areas**) from https://gadm.org/data.html

```
import geopandas as gpd
World = gpd.read_file("~/gadm36.shp")
World=World[['NAME_0','NAME_1','NAME_2','geometry']] #Keep only 3 columns
World.head()
```

[image]

In this GeoDataFrame, I have **60 columns** (**NAME_0**: for country name, **NAME_1** for the region, ...)

For now, I am interested in studying the number of users of my website in Germany

```
Germany=World[World['NAME_0'].isin(['Germany']) == True]
```

Now here my website users data by region (NAME_1), I renamed the first column to be the same in shapefile

```
GER = pd.read_csv("~/GER.CSV",sep=";") 
GER
```

[image]

Now I merge my data to GeoDataFrame on NAME_1 to plot users in regions

```
merged_ger = Germany.merge(GER, on = 'NAME_1', how='left') 
merged_ger['Users'] = merged_ger['Users'].fillna(0)
```

The problem here is that **NAME_1** is repeated according to **NAME_2**. Thus, the total number of users in the merged data greatly exceeds the original number

```
print(merged_ger['Users'].sum())
print(GER['Users'].sum())

7172411.0
74529
```

So plot data using this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
merged_ger.plot(column='Users')
```

is obviously **wrong**

[image]

How can I merge the data in this case without duplication and without affecting the final plot?
Or, how do I ignore the rest of the administrative areas in a shapefile?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't mapping a dictionary of user's region help?

```
GER_users = dict(zip(GER.NAME_1, GER.Users))
Germany['Users'] = Germany['NAME_1'].map(GER_users)
```